# Inflating class map fragment error when return to the previous map fragment

Tags: android, fragment, supportmapfragment

I have a FragmentActivity which replaces differents fragment to show information. One of those fragments (StepTwoAddressFragment) has a map contained in its layout. The first time, this fragment draws the views correctly, but when I back to this fragment in the stack, the app crashes. I need to add this fragment to the fragment back stack.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

FragmentActivity

```
switch (mCurrentSection) {
    case SECTION_STEP_TWO_MAPS_ADDRESS:
        SelectNewPositionFragment fragm = SelectNewPositionFragment.newInstance();
        mCurrentFragment = fragm;
        break;

    case SECTION_STEP_TWO_ADDRESS:
        mCurrentFragment = StepTwoAddressFragment.newInstance();
        break;

    case SECTION_STEP_TWO_WHY_GO:
        mCurrentFragment = StepTwoWhyGoFragment.newInstance();
        break;
}

if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content_frame, mCurrentFragment);
    if (hasToAddToBackStack()) {
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    ft.commit();
}

private boolean hasToAddToBackStack() {
    return mCurrentSection != SECTION_STEP_TWO_MAPS_ADDRESS || mCurrentSection != SECTION_STEP_TWO_ADDRESS;
}
```

fragment_selected_new_position_layout.xml

```
................

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

................
```

SelectNewPositionFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selected_new_position_layout, container, false);

    //mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = mapFragment.getMap();

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (mapFragment.isResumed()) {
        ft.remove(mapFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I tried this code too:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }
    return view;
}
```

**SOLUTION**
I change the fragment view in the layout and change it with a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I create a new class MapBaseFragment which extends the SupportMapFragment class and initializes the map.

```
public class MapBaseFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

...

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setUpMap();
    }

...

}
```

and the Fragment which contains the map

```
mapFragment = new MapBaseFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment);
ft.commit();
```

Finally, delete the onDestroyView code.

It's right for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `FragmentTransaction.add()` instead of `FragmentTransaction.replace()`.

This will keep that fragment that contains the map underneath your new fragment.

You will probably want to set the background opaque and add it to the back stack with `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`